# Finding similar strings in array

Tags: php, arrays, similarity

I need to harness [`similar_text()`](http://php.net/similar_text) for an array of values that look something like this:

```
$strings = ["lawyer" => 3, "business" => 3, "lawyers" => 1, "a" => 3];
```

What I'm trying to do is find the words what are practically the same, i.e. `lawyer` and `lawyers` in the above array, and add the counts for them together in a new array.

So `lawyer` would be `4` as `lawyers` would be associated to the original string of `lawyer`.

Keep in mind, this array will only ever be singular words and the length is unspecified, it could range from `1` to `>99`.

I had no idea where to start with this, so I gave it a crack with a foreach loop as you'll see below, but the intended output isn't as expected.

```
foreach ( $strings as $key_one => $count_one ) {
    foreach ( $strings as $key_two => $count_two ) {
        similar_text($key_two, $key_one, $percent);
        if ($percent > 80) {
            if(!isset($counts[$key_one])) {
                $counts[$key_one] = $count_one;
            } else {
                $counts[$key_one] += $count_two;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

<sup>**Note:** *The percent match is at `80` for this example (as the match for `lawyer` & `lawyers` is `~92%`)*</sup>

Which ends up giving me something similar to the following:

```
Array
(
    [lawyer] => 4
    [business] => 3
    [a] => 3
    [lawyers] => 2
)
```

Where I require it to be:

```
Array
(
    [lawyer] => 4
    [business] => 3
    [a] => 3
)
```

<sup>*Notice how i require it to practically remove `lawyers` and add the count to `lawyer`.*</sup>

Comment: Why don't you transform it to oop? Then you could just register and deregister objects. Like all words are initially registered to object master, if a match is found the match is removed from master and regsitered to the match. That way you preserve the values and you can dynamically insert words if needed.

Comment: maybe you want to take a look at the Levenshtein distance algorithm [small description on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)

Comment: @MichaelDibbets Thanks for that comment! I've figured out how to get it now, I just have to remove the item from the array so that it doesn't get set in the newly created array. If you want to post that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @RaphaelMüller Thank you for that comment as-well, I had a read of the wiki and it is a rather interesting algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use

```
unset( $counts[$key_two] ) ;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your difficulty is that just as lawyer is similar to lawyers, lawyers is also similar to lawyer. So they both get their count bumped up by the other.

Try this:

```
foreach ( $strings as $key_one => &$count_one ) {
    if ($count_one == 0) continue; // skip it if we've already processed it
    if (!isset($counts[$key_one]) {
        $counts[$key_one] = $count_one;
        $count_one = 0;
    }
    foreach ( $strings as $key_two => &$count_two ) {
        similar_text($key_two, $key_one, $percent);
        if ($percent > 80) {
            $counts[$key_one] += $count_two;
            $count_two = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

The disadvantage of that is that you change your original $strings array which may not be ideal.  Here's another approach, keeping track of already-processed strings in another hash:

```
$already = $counts = array(); // not really necessary, but nice to init
foreach ( $strings as $key_one => $count_one ) {
    if (isset($already[$key_one])) continue; // skip if already processed
    $counts[$key_one] = $count_one; // by definition this should be new
    foreach ( $strings as $key_two => $count_two ) {
        similar_text($key_two, $key_one, $percent);
        if ($percent > 80) {
            $counts[$key_one] += $count_two;
            $already[$key_two] = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I would recommend the 2nd solution.